# A * Heuristic for Sliding Puzzle is not working as expected

Tags: java, algorithm, puzzle, path-finding

I am implementing a solver for a sliding puzzle. In one implementation, I used a Breadth First Search. In the second one, I am using A *. However, A * is going slower than the BFS approach. I measured the average time for BFS to solve a 9x9 puzzle is around .227 seconds whereas for A * it is taking almost 2 seconds long.

The heuristic I am using for A * is the following : F = G + H where G is the number of blocks out of order and H is the combined sum of manhattan distance for every tile to its supposed position in the goal state (which the user defines).

Here is the relevant parts of A * code (The comparator is used in a priority queue):

```
private void addToPriorityQueue(PuzzleState nextPS) {
    if (nextPS != null && !this.visited.contains(nextPS))
        pQueue.add(nextPS);
}

private boolean solveByAStar() {
    pQueue.clear();
    pQueue.add(this.initialState);

    while(!pQueue.isEmpty()) { 
        if (pQueue.size() > maxQueueSize)
            maxQueueSize = pQueue.size();

        this.currentState = pQueue.poll();

        if (this.currentState.equals(finalState)) { 
            return true;
        }

        visited.add(this.currentState);

        this.addToPriorityQueue(this.currentState.moveUp());
        this.addToPriorityQueue(this.currentState.moveDown());
        this.addToPriorityQueue(this.currentState.moveRight());
        this.addToPriorityQueue(this.currentState.moveLeft());

    }
    return false;
}

private class puzzleStateComparator implements Comparator<PuzzleState> {

    @Override
    public int compare(PuzzleState o1, PuzzleState o2) {
        //TODO

        int[] goalState = FastPuzzleSolver.this.initialState.getStateArray();

        int o1GScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.numBlocksOutOfPlace(o1.getStateArray(), goalState);
        int o2GScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.numBlocksOutOfPlace(o2.getStateArray(), goalState);

        int o1HScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.calculateManhattanDistanceSum(o1.getStateArray(), goalState);
        int o2HScore = PuzzlePropertyUtility.calculateManhattanDistanceSum(o2.getStateArray(), goalState);



        return Integer.compare(o2GScore + o2HScore, o1GScore + o1HScore);


    }

}
```

And here are the methods used to calculate G and H :

```
public static int numBlocksOutOfPlace(int[] ps, int[] goal) {
    int difference = 0;
    for (int i : ps) {
        if (ps[i] != goal[i])
                difference++;
    }
    return difference;
}

public static int calculateManhattanDistanceSum(int[] ps, int[] goal) {
    int rowSz = calculatePuzzleRowSize(ps);
    int manhattanDistanceSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ps.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ps.length; j++) {
            if (ps[i] == goal[j])
                manhattanDistanceSum += (Math.abs(i/rowSz - j/rowSz) + Math.abs(i%rowSz - j%rowSz)); 
        }
    }
    return manhattanDistanceSum;
}
```

Is the reason behind the slowness because of the efficiency of my code or is it that my heuristic is flawed or both?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code with VisualVM or a similar tool?

Comment: @chrylis I printed out the moves and it seems my heuristic is counter productive as it takes much more moves to arrive at the goal state.

Comment: You seem to be sorting your states based on the heuristic function, but you should sort them on the distance from the source + the heuristic function. If you only use the heuristic score, then chances are it will go in more or less random directions. Also, you seem to be using a combination of two heuristics? IMO, you should get it working with just one first, to make sure that works well. More heuristics are not always correct (they may become inadmissible if you add them), let alone better.

Comment: @IVlad Do you mean source as in the current state?

Comment: @Renren29 - no, the source is the state that you start from. See the wikipedia entry of A* for an implementation.

Comment: @IVlad hi i figured out the reason. I put the wrong order of comparison in the compare method. i just switched o1 abd o2 and now the algorithm is really fast.